# Installing multiple versions of Visual Studio Team Editions on the same machine

Tags: visual-studio

Does anyone have any experience with installing multiple versions of Team edition on the same machine? For example Team Developer and Team Architect at the same time? Is this possible? Do you have to open one version vs the other? Or do you end up with one installation with all the versions installed on top of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can happily install multiple versions.  When you install the second one it simply add the features into the same Visual Studio 2008 instance meaning you get the features of both in the same instance of the IDE.

That said, the way licensing works it is usually cheaper to purchase Visual Studio Team Suite (which includes all the features) then purchasing 2 seperate SKU's.

Answer (score 0):

My guess will be that each new installation will overwrite the previous in your instance. See this: [image: relationship of various Visual Studio Editions]

With Team system being on one level, my guess is only one can be installed.

Comment: Actually pasted an img url from wikipedia: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/Visual_Studio_Editions_Compact.svg