# What if I install both Visual Studio 2008 Developer and Database Editions

Tags: visual-studio

Some visual studio plugin only support Developer Edition. While I only have Database Edition installed.
I bet I am able to install both. But i have no clue is that means I have two different instances of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487501/installing-multiple-versions-of-visual-studio-team-editions-on-the-same-machine) question your machine will just have one instance of Visual Studio, but it will have the features of both editions (Developer and Database) you installed.